# Failed prop type: FocusZone: prop type `as` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, fluent

I'm getting this warning in react js while using Fluent UI components. I tried a lot of things but unable to remove this warning. anyone has idea?

> Code

```
<Dialog        
        as="div"
        className="PopupDialogs"
        open={showPopUp}
        styles={{ justifySelf: "unset" }}
        header={GetSubject()}
        content={<Flex>{displayTime}</Flex>}
        footer={footer()}
        onCancel={() => { OnClosePopUp(false) }}
        onConfirm={() => { }}
        headerAction={context.userProfileData.isTeacher && headerAction()}
    />
```

---

> Warning

```
backend.js:6 Warning: Failed prop type: FocusZone: prop type `as` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.
    in FocusZone (created by Menu)
    in Menu (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in section (created by Context.Consumer)
    in u (created by Context.Consumer)
    in f (created by Context.Consumer)
    in s (created by component)
    in component (created by Context.Consumer)
    in t (created by D)
    in t (created by D)
    in D
    in t (created by t)
    in t
    in div (created by ProviderBox)
    in ProviderBox (created by Provider)
    in Unknown (created by Provider)
    in s (created by Provider)
    in Provider
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: show your proptypes code in your component.

Comment: i have added code

Comment: this type of error occur if you are passing wrong type of value as props to your child try to figure out what you are passing wrong you can refer example here https://microsoft.github.io/fluent-ui-react/components/dialog/definition